# angular material 2 md-sidenav mode="over" option not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created an angular project using the Angular ClI and installed material version `2.0.0-beta.11`.

I tried to create a sidenav with the `@Input() mode` as `"over"`. However, it does not work correctly. Here's my code:

```html
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav mode="over" #sidenav align="end" class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

And here's the output:

[image: Actual output]

The same code is working fine in the [plunker] (https://plnkr.co/edit/pFASnvScn3M78FUtyfmE?p=preview)

Why is it not working on my local machine?

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clean up your question it’s hard to read the code and can you provide input and expected output along with what you actually got?

Comment: I forgot to include theme in project after including theme it was working as excepted. Thanks